# Glassfish Servlet Error 500 (not exception) - Upload file bigger than 20mb

Tags: java, file, servlets, upload, glassfish

**UPDATE**

Tried it now on another computer and it worked fine, should be something wrong with my glassfish, if anyone have an idea without reinstalling it i would be glad.

**END_UPDATE**

I'm trying to create an simple servlet that receive an file and do something with it, but even with the simplest example possible it's not working for file larger than 20mb.

The big problem is that glassfish does not log anything and the error does not show any exception at all and the message is very generic.

Another important thing is that the doPost() is not even called when the file is larger than 20mb, the error is throw before that.

Here is the error that is displayed:

[image]

Other thing is that the message show HTTP Status 500, but the real status is 400 (Bad Request).

Here is the Servlet that i'm using:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@WebServlet("/upload")
@MultipartConfig(location = "/tmp")
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/upload.jsp").forward(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Collection<Part> parts = req.getParts();
        for(Part part : parts) {
            System.out.println("Name:");
            System.out.println(part.getName());
            System.out.println("Header: ");
            for(String headerName : part.getHeaderNames()) {
                System.out.println(headerName);
                System.out.println(part.getHeader(headerName));
            }
            System.out.println("Size: ");
            System.out.println(part.getSize());
            part.write(part.getName() + "-down");
        }
        res.sendRedirect("/upload");
    }
}
```

And here is the simple jsp (but the error is throw even using an POST tool, like Postman):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>File Upload Sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <p>
                <label>Select a file: </label>
                <input type="file" name="file"/>
            </p>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>Portabilidade</display-name>
    <!-- location of log4j config file -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I'm already with no more idea on how to fix that...

Comment: There has to be an exception stacktrace in your server.log. Please add it to the question.

Comment: As i said in the topic, there's no exception, no error, nothing.., i checked it...

Answer (score 0):

Check your
Network Config > Protocols > http-listener-2
Under the HTTP setting is "Max Post Size:". You can set this to -1 to disable.

I had mine set to 25MB at some point and the behavior OP described is what I experienced for any file upload larger than this value.